# How can I send an error over a pipe in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pipe

I have a multi-threaded C program, and I create a pipe to send data between theads. I have one thread that generates the data and writes it to the pipe, and then another thread that reads data from the pipe and consumes it. And the happy path works correctly. However, I'm having issues when the write side of the pipe has an error.

I know, that upon reading the data on the read side, that `read()` will return the number of bytes read upon success, and 0 to indicate EOF, and "On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately." So, what I would like to do when I get an error on the write thread is do something that intentionally results in the read side getting a -1 return value from `read()`. This would let the read thread know there is an error, and it can go into its error handling code.

My issue is that I can't find a way to intentionally do anything to the pipe descriptor on the write thread that will result in an error when reading from the read pipe descriptor. `close()` just asks for the file descriptor and closes it. The `write()` man page seems to describe many problems that will return an error to the caller, but, as far as I tell, nothing that will result in an error to whoever is reading from the other end of the pipe.

So: Is there anything I can intentionally do in the thread with the write pipe descriptor that will result in the thread with the read pipe descriptor getting a -1 return value when calling `read()`?

Comment: `close(fd);` should do it

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, No, that would have to be done on the reader's end to be an error on the reader's end. (Doing it on the writers end will result on EOF, not an error.)

Comment: If you keep track of (manage) the processes, you could signal the related process to indicate an exception (`SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`, with the side effect to interrupt any blocked - interruptable - state).

Answer (score 3):

> So: Is there anything I can intentionally do in the thread with the write pipe descriptor that will result in the thread with the read pipe descriptor getting a -1 return value when calling `read()`?

No.  Error status reports on errors.  It does not provide a side channel for communication.

Your simplest alternative would be for the writer to close its end of the pipe.  Supposing that it's not open anywhere else then the reader will perceive EOF when it exhausts the pipe buffer and then tries to read more.

The next simplest would probably be for your protocol to provide for exchanging error information.  This becomes more attractive if it is important to keep the pipe open.

Then there are various *bona fide* side channels possible, such as another pipe, shared memory, and raising signals.

---

Note, however, that although the reader has all the same side-channel options, the effect of it closing (the last open file descriptor for) the read end of the pipe is that the writer will indeed get an error (`EPIPE`, normally) when it next tries to write to the pipe.  This is considered a *bona fide* error.

Answer (score 1):

> I have one thread that generates the data and writes it to the pipe, and then another thread that reads data from the pipe and consumes it.

That's a simplistic way of looking at it. Pipes don't really carry *data.* Pipes carry sequences of bytes. In order for a sequence of bytes to mean something, there must be some kind of *encoding.* If the bytes are stored in a file, we talk about the [*file format*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format). If the bytes are part of a two-way dialog over a wire or through a pipe, we talk about a [*protocol*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol).

Your application is using a protocol to send data. But it sounds as if the protocol may not be defined by anything except your working code.

You need a better protocol. Instead of having the one thread simply send "data" whenever. You need it to send some kind of a token (could be as simple as a single byte) that means, "here comes some data." And, when there's an error, you need it to send a *different* token (different byte) that means, "here comes an error code and/or message."

Protocols can be dirt simple, or they can be hugely complicated, but either way, they are best if they are *documented.* Google is your friend. Good luck.